# Integrals, absolute value problem

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

if $ 0 \le  c \le  2$, calculate:

$\int _0^2\:\left|x^2-c\right|dx$

I only know $\int _0^2\:(x^2-c)dx = 8/3 - 2c $

Answer (score 1):

$$
|x^2-c|=\begin{cases}x^2-c,\text{ if } x\ge\sqrt c\\
c-x^2,\text{ if } x<\sqrt c
\end{cases}$$
So your integral becomes
$$
\int_0^\sqrt c(c-x^2)\,dx+\int_\sqrt c^2(x^2-c)\,dx
$$